# jQuery append value on click and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append the `button` text to the `span` but have it only show the value from the last clicked `button` under each `.item`.

So whatever the `button` text is that is clicked, `append` it to the `span` and have that value replaced by the next pressed `button` text, and so on.

```js
$(".list").on("click", ".button", function() {
  var x = $(this).closest(".item");
  var y = $(".button").text();
  $('#value').append('(' + y + ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <button class="button">50</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <button class="button">30</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <button class="button">70</button>
  </div>
</div>
<span id="value">Total:</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would structure your html a little like this and then target the span and update it using `.text()`. I used the `<span>` inside of the `<p>` tag like this because if you try and update the whole span tag, it'll also remove the `total:` text. I also trimmed up the jquery here a little bit by removing `var x = $(this).closest(".item");` as we didn't need it in this case (not sure what that was in there for).

```
$('#value span').text(y);
```

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  var y = $(this).text();
  $('#value span').text(y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <button class="button">50</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <button class="button">30</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <button class="button">70</button>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="value">Total: (<span>0</span>)</p>
```

Comment: In reference to the **actual question**.. what is the purpose of `var x = $(this).closest(".item");`?

Comment: @M12Bennett Ah good point. I'll update the answer to include little edits I did.

Comment: I'm just saying.. `x` is created but never used.. really the OP should answer that

Comment: I definitely agree there. I removed it for now to keep things clean.

Comment: I was using the click function to find elements inside of each `.item` from the `.list` and return the contents. Example being: `$("#title").text(t.find(".title").text()),` finds the `.title` inside of the item, and returns the contents to `#title` on the click of `.button`

Comment: I just realized that I have the `.button` value nested inside of `.button` in a separate div (named `.total`). How do I call that div specifically because right now this code returns all of the contents inside of `.button`.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill To avoid confusion, can you post up a quick fiddle in this comment thread for me to check out? It sounds like you can access it normally with `#('.total')`, but again the fiddle would make things all clear.

Comment: Here is a codepen. I added the other div as an example of my markup https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/zLJoBy

Comment: Ah ok so you just want the number value with the '+' sign, right?

Answer (score 2):

**The Issue:**

What you've asked jQuery to do is to append the text value of every object with a class of '.button', since all three buttons have that class, you're getting the text value of each button no matter which you click.

**The Solution:**

Use the 'this' keyword! In the context of a click listener, the 'this' keyword will refer to the control that fired the event. In other words, the control that was clicked. Now you will only be appending the value of one button with each click.

**For Example:**

```js
$(".list").on("click", ".button", function () {
    var y = $(this).text();
    $('#value').append('(' + y + ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <button class="button">50</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <button class="button">30</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Item 3</div>
            <button class="button">70</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="value">Total:</span>
```

Hope that helps!

** -EDIT- **

To REPLACE the value with each click you'd want to use the .text() method to insert the value into the text property of the control. Since you currently have "Total" in there, you'd also need to insert that programatically, or like I did, move it outside your span element.

```js
$(".list").on("click", ".button", function () {
    var y = $(this).text();
    // Use .text instead of .append.
    $('#value').text('(' + y + ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <button class="button">50</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <button class="button">30</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Item 3</div>
            <button class="button">70</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>Total: <span id="value"></span></div>
```

Comment: Part of the question is also to remove the previous value once a new value has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just replace

```
$('#value').append('(' + y + ')');
```

with

```
$('#value').html('(Total:' + y + ')');
```